# environment variables not working with React and variables [NODE]

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I have a problem with my environment variables. It is like variables doesn't exist.

Here a picture of my problem:
[image: Here a picture of my problem]

in the `.env` :

`REACT_APP_GET_CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3002/api/clients/${res.data.userId}?access_token=${res.data.id}`

and this is where I call the env :

```
login: (data) => {
    axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGIN_URL, data)
    .then((res) => {
       localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.id)
       localStorage.setItem('userId', res.data.userId)
       axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_GET_CLIENT_URL)
       .then((res) => {
           localStorage.setItem('firstName', res.data.firstName)
           localStorage.setItem('lastName', res.data.lastName)
           localStorage.setItem('picture', res.data.picture)
           localStorage.setItem('namePicture', res.data.namePicture)
           dispatch({type: 'LOGIN'});  
           }) 
       }
       ).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_ERR'});
   })
},
```

`process.env.REACT_APP_LOGIN_URL` is working with :

`REACT_APP_LOGIN_URL = http://localhost:3002/api/clients/login`

thank you in advance

Comment: The value of the variable is determined at the time of creation, not use. Perhaps there are some other methods to do this. I would use the pattern and `.replace`

Comment: @bato3 could you tell me more about your idea please

Comment: definition: `REACT_APP_GET_CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3002/api/clients/:userId:?access_token=:token"` and usage: `REACT_APP_GET_CLIENT_URL.replace(':userId:', res.data.userId).replace(':token:', res.data.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bato3, it is working now !

I resume here :

```
login: (data) => {
        axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGIN_URL, data)
          .then((res) => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.id)
            localStorage.setItem('userId', res.data.userId)
            let REACT_APP_GET_CLIENT_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_GET_CLIENT_URL
              axios.get(REACT_APP_GET_CLIENT_URL.replace(':userId:', res.data.userId).replace(':token:', res.data.id))
              .then((res) => {
              console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_GET_CLIENT_URL)
              localStorage.setItem('firstName', res.data.firstName)
              localStorage.setItem('lastName', res.data.lastName)
              localStorage.setItem('picture', res.data.picture)
              localStorage.setItem('namePicture', res.data.namePicture)
              dispatch({type: 'LOGIN'});  
              }) 
          }
          ).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_ERR'});
        })
        },
```

in the `.env`:

```
REACT_APP_GET_CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3002/api/clients/:userId:?access_token=:token"
```

Thank you !